как сделать подключение с разных компов у сокета
не особо шарю и прошу вас помочь как мне сделать подключение у полностью разных компьютеров то есть нет возможности подключения их к одной сети 

Что значит - полностью разных компов?

Вам нужно купить сервер и запускать серверную часть на сервере.

хахахахахахахахаах

Вопрос довольно размытый и требует уточнения.
Если речь идет про обмен данными, проще всего подключить компы к одному wifi. Тогда у машин будет доступ к файлам друг друга.
Подробнее здесь: https://wifigid.ru/virtualnaya-wi-fi-set/kak-soedinit-pk-s-pk-po-wi-fi.
При чем так можно даже винду с линуксом подружить.
Более тесное объединение компов, как мне кажется, не целесообразно.

у меня компы и их нельзя подключить к одной сети
